# How to get rid of the h1 element that that summernote wraps it's content with

Tags: html, laravel, summernote

I'm using summernote to create a post in a Laravel project and everything works fine. However, when I display the content `{!! post->content !!}` the content displays as expected but it's wrapped in an `<h1 dir="ltr" style="...">...</h1>` .

I already have an `h1` tag so this causes me to have two `h1 tags`.

Is there a way to ensure the content is not wrapped in an `h1`?

An example of an output after checking out the page source

```
<h1 dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 20pt; margin-bottom: 6pt">
  <br />
  <p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt">
    <span
      style="
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        white-space: pre;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
      "
      >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi consequatur
      facilis ipsa placeat veniam itaque!</span
    >
  </p>
  <p>
    <b
      style="font-weight: normal"
      id="docs-internal-guid-47f21b1f-7fff-8d45-a008-bd6623b10047"
      ><br
    /></b>
  </p>
  <p dir="ltr" style="line-height: 1.38; margin-top: 0pt; margin-bottom: 0pt">
    <span
      style="
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-family: Arial;
        color: #000000;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        white-space: pre;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
      "
      >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi consequatur
      facilis ipsa placeat veniam itaque!
    </span>
  </p>
  <p><br /></p>
</h1>
```

Comment: Are there other tags in the `post->content`? ... you may be able to use the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function. You can also specify tags to keep, if any, with that function too.

Comment: @PaulT., Yes, I've updated the question and provided an example from the page source.

Comment: Ok, so try the function previously mentioned: `{{!! strip_tags($post->content, '<b><br><p><span>') !!}}` ... the list of tags as the second parameter are the tags to _allow_.

Comment: That works, thanks. However, the tags will be dynamic. Allowing all tags except `h1` will do for my goal. I'm going through the link you've shared to see if there is a way to achieve that but if you have a solution for that kindly share.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, there is not an option to only remove a _specific_ tag, but only to specify what tags to _allow_, which can be a long list depending upon use.